# problem with upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, upgrade, 16.04

I upgraded Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, but I had some problems with installation, so I wondered if I could install 16.04 again without using USB memory stick or DVD? Or if I can return to 14.04

Comment: "so I wondered if I could instal 16.04 lts"again

Comment: probably this is not possible cause it is not windows , well you could a reinstall the ubuntu from usb stick without losing your files and dont know about 16.04 , but in 14.04 you could create a bootable usb of the the os without any iso from the startup disk creator.

Comment: Why can't you use the USB stick or DVD again?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this solution: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318779&p=13466943#post13466943
If you can login in the terminal, then you are able to do this simple procedure. Essential should be the line `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (if you run as root, you don't need the `sudo`) and you can gracefully poweroff after that using `sudo poweroff`. It helped a some other people, like here [Error after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/816303/error-after-upgrading-from-14-04-to-16-04/816316?noredirect=1#comment1243873_816316)