# Error after upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

While upgrading from 14.04 to 16.04.1, the notebook stopped working. I restarted it. Now, when I push on the power button, it shows a message: `Failed to install kernel modules`, and my last screen looks like a terminal, there is no GUI.

Can I repair this by undoing the upgrade and run the 14.04 version, just like before trying to upgrade?

The specs for my notebook are:
  ASUS model S451LBRA
  processor: Intel core i7 4500U
  video card: Intek HD Graphics 4000
  6GB DDR3 SDRAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you must first find the problem. You can still login using your username and password (which will not appear as you type).
You should provide what hardware you use, like laptop manufacturer, model number. This is written on the laptop usually. You can also provide the output of these commands `cat /proc/cpuinfo | sort | uniq | grep model`, `lspci`, `lsusb`, `free -h`. You can then poweroff your laptop using the same command.

For better usability, read up on these tools: `ls`, `cd`, `man`. It will make your life easier in such situations as now.

You can probably fix your installation using a life-CD such as a Ubuntu installer. Without more detail, nobody will really be able to help.

Comment: The specs for my notebook are: ASUS model S451LBRA processor intel core i7 4500U video card Intek HD Graphics 4000, 6GB DDR3 SDRAM

Comment: Is there anyway, a comman perhaps, to return to previous version, the 14.04 LTS ?

Comment: Can you please provide the output of `dmesg`?

Comment: Ok, the whole output is longer than i thought. moew than 4 screens displays. i can´t

Comment: You can put it somewhere as a text file to download, right?

Comment: Hey Adam i cab send you a filé. How can attach ? Can you passar me your email?

Comment: Can you upload it do Google Drive/ Dropbox/ Onedrive and share a link? Other people could help you that way also. I have an exam on friday, so I will attend to your problem after that.

Comment: Ok, here it go!! I can not copy the text appeared on the terminal screen. How can i do this ?   I took photos    https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Xwloat4waKV1NDNW9NVHFxTzg

Comment: Some other people have a similar problem after an upgrade, I tried to search "systemd-modules-load.service status failure ubuntu 16.04 upgrade"
For you, it seems, you are able to login. So I would run the upgrade/ configure procedure (as sudo) https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2318779&p=13466943#post13466943
Then reboot using `sudo poweroff` (or reboot). For some people especially the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a` seems to do the job but please do run the other commands in that order too.

Comment: Please vote it up then :-)